# plot heatmap including NA

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting a heatmap of the following csv file:

```
"people","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
"Ej1",0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0
"Ej2",0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0
"Ej3",0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej4",0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1
"Ej5",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1
"Ej6",1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
"Ej7",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1
"Ej8",0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
"Ej9",1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

Using the following code I get the heatmap below and works fine

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(plyr)
data <- read.csv("fruits2.txt", head=TRUE, sep=",")
data$people <- factor(data$people,levels=rev(data$people))
data.m = melt(data)
#data.m <- ddply(data.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
data.m[,"rescale"]<-rescale(data.m[,"value"],to=c(0,1))
fewer.labels <- c("Ej9","Ej8","Ej7","Ej6","Ej5","Ej4","Ej3","Ej2","Ej1")
p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(variable, people)) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
     scale_y_discrete(labels=fewer.labels) +
     scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to plot the same fruits.txt file but including some missing values, therefore the file includes  NA values. When the entire column is NA then it doesn't plot that column, would it be possible to plot that column shaded as it does with isolated NA values?

```
"people","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
"Ej1",0,0,0,1,0,1,1,NA,0
"Ej2",0,1,1,0,0,0,1,NA,0
"Ej3",0,1,1,1,0,0,0,NA,1
"Ej4",0,NA,0,0,NA,1,0,NA,1
"Ej5",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,NA,1
"Ej6",1,1,0,1,1,1,0,NA,0
"Ej7",0,1,1,0,0,0,0,NA,1
"Ej8",0,0,1,1,1,1,1,NA,0
"Ej9",1,1,0,0,1,0,0,NA,NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the `id` variable in `melt`, both `people` and column `8` are treated as ids, and you loose X8 in the variable column of the molten data. You then do not get variable X8 plotted in the heatmap.

Using `melt(data,id='people')` should solve it.

[image]